# 15.04 working slow on my pc

Tags: grubrescue

A few days ago my hard drive died and now I have a problem.

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my 16GB pendrive. When I use Ubuntu it acts very slowly.

I tried my best to solve this problem but can't. My PC has 3GB RAM and 2GB video RAM. The processor is an Intel dual-core @3GHz and the motherboard is an Intel dg41wv. Why is my computer so slow?

Comment: the bottleneck is on your pendrive. How fast I/O it can take?

Comment: Like @AizuddinZali said, this is probably the fact that you have Ubuntu installed on a USB drive. Unfortunately, there's nothing really to be done to speed it up, since USB drives have a very low transfer speed compared to internal hard drives, and performance should not be expected to be fast. If it is just programs and such taking a while to open, the problem is Ubuntu being on a USB drive. If the cursor is slow and videos stutter and lag, then it may be something else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that USB Pendrive can't hold `I/O per secs` as much as normal HDD would take.

Therefore, resulting in performance loss of your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Hey please try with another usb drive of 3.0 which may take effect

And try for your HDD by hard format of type

```
ext4
```

if you trid that one and no response yet there then try formatting by the time of installation it will take effect

And such problem may happen due to your incompatible graphics card

You may check following link also [disable incompatible graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454436/14-04-how-to-disable-discrete-graphics-card)